# Simple pine script trading startegy

Tags: pine-script

I am new to pine script.

I am trying to achieve a strategy based on crosses of the bollinger bands.

However I am struggling with setting stop orders.

I would like to set a stop order based on the entry price and held in the variables **Stop_short** and **Stop_long** in order to exit long  short positions when the price goes belo/ above that price

Is anyone able to help?

```
//@version=3

// BACKTESTING RANGE
 
// From Date Inputs
fromDay = input(defval = 29, title = "From Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
fromMonth = input(defval = 9, title = "From Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
fromYear = input(defval = 2021, title = "From Year", minval = 1970)
 
// To Date Inputs
toDay = input(defval = 28, title = "To Day", minval = 1, maxval = 31)
toMonth = input(defval = 1, title = "To Month", minval = 1, maxval = 12)
toYear = input(defval = 2023, title = "To Year", minval = 1970)
 
// Calculate start/end date and time condition
startDate = timestamp(fromYear, fromMonth, fromDay, 00, 00)
finishDate = timestamp(toYear, toMonth, toDay, 00, 00)
time_cond = time >= startDate and time <= finishDate

// Set stop loss level with input options (optional)
Lossperc_Long = input(title="Long Stop Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01

Lossperc_Short = input(title="Short Stop Loss (%)",
     type=float, minval=0.0, step=0.1, defval=1) * 0.01
 

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


// 1. Define strategy settings
strategy(title="Bollinger Breakout OBI", overlay=true,
     pyramiding=0, initial_capital=100000,
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_order,
     commission_value=4, slippage=2)

smaLength = input(title="SMA Length", type=integer, defval=20)
stdLength = input(title="StdDev Length", type=integer, defval=20)

ubOffset = input(title="Upper Band Offset", type=float, defval=2.0, step=0.5)
lbOffset = input(title="Lower Band Offset", type=float, defval=2.0, step=0.5)

usePosSize = input(title="Use Position Sizing?", type=bool, defval=true)
riskPerc   = input(title="Risk %", type=float, defval=0.5, step=0.25)

// 2. Calculate strategy values
smaValue = sma(close, smaLength)
stdDev   = stdev(close, stdLength)

upperBand = smaValue + (stdDev * ubOffset)
lowerBand = smaValue - (stdDev * lbOffset)


///////////// RSI
RSIlength = input(16,title="RSI Period Length")
RSIoverSold = input(40,title="RSI Oversold")
RSIoverBought = input(60,title="RSI Overbought")  
price = close
vrsi = rsi(price, RSIlength)


///////////// POSITION SIZING
riskEquity  = (riskPerc / 100) * strategy.equity
atrCurrency = (atr(20) * syminfo.pointvalue)
posSize     = usePosSize ? floor(riskEquity / atrCurrency) : 1




// 3. Output strategy data

// BB PLOT
plot(series=smaValue, title="SMA", color=teal)

plot(series=upperBand, title="UB", color=green,
     linewidth=2)
plot(series=lowerBand, title="LB", color=red,
     linewidth=2)

// 4. Determine long trading conditions
enterLong = crossover(close, lowerBand) and (vrsi < RSIoverSold)
exitLong  = crossunder(close, lowerBand)
Stop_long = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 - Lossperc_Long)

// 5. Code short trading conditions
enterShort = crossunder(close, upperBand) and (vrsi > RSIoverBought)
exitShort  = crossunder(close, lowerBand)
Stop_short = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + Lossperc_Short)

//Price_entry = strategy.opentrades (strategy.opentrades - 1)


// 6. Submit entry orders
if (enterLong) and time_cond
    strategy.entry(id="EL", long=true, qty=posSize)

if (enterShort) and time_cond
    strategy.entry(id="ES", long=false, qty=posSize)

// 7. Submit exit orders
strategy.close(id="EL", when=exitLong)
strategy.close(id="ES", when=exitShort)
strategy.exit(id="EL",stop=Stop_short)
strategy.exit(id="ES",stop=Stop_long)


plot(close + 2*atr(20), color=yellow )
plot(close - 2*atr(20), color=yellow)
```

Comment: Why v3?. Are you using chatGPT?.
Due to such poor accuracy [Stackoverflow has banned ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).
TradingView has also decided [not to provide any QA support for ChatGPT](http://tradingview.com/chart/TRAIA/XwwZ70ar-Our-take-on-AI-generated-Pine-Script/).

Answer (score 0):

Convert your code to the latest version (v5)
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html

In this way, you could use debugging tools
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/writing/Debugging.html#debugging

For example, *comment_loss* in strategy.exit
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_strategy%7Bdot%7Dexit

```
strategy.exit(id="EL",stop=Stop_short, comment_loss = 'sl')
```

and
Plot the *Stop_long* and *Stop_short* line to help you in your analysis